# At high altitudes, does reentry cause the atmosphere to burn, or only heat up?

Tags: temperature, physical-chemistry, atmospheric-science, plasma-physics

A Google search reveals the following about high altitude reentry:

> A re-entering vehicle develops a very energetic pressure wave at its leading surfaces. The energy density is sufficient to cause atmospheric molecules to dissociate, and their component atoms to become ionized. The vehicle thus descends in a superheated shroud of incandescent plasma. ([Source](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2016/11/17/this-is-why-objects-burn-when-they-re-enter-the-atmosphere/?sh=8c2899c6963f))

Once the reentry vehicle passes any particular point in the atmosphere, and the atmosphere begins to cool, is there a combustion byproduct (e.g., the oxygen burns with something to create a new molecule)? Or did the plasma merely heat up and, upon cooling down, return to the original gaseous state?

Answer (score 3):

Reentry can cause oxidation of atmospheric nitrogen and leave some nitric oxide ([NASA TM X-62,052 , ESTIMATES OF NITRIC OXIDE PRODUCTION FOR LIFTING SPACECRAFT REENTRY, July 1971](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19720024212/downloads/19720024212.pdf)).
.